# Onedrive oauth, code-flow step 2 not working

Tags: node.js, https, oauth-2.0, onedrive

I'm trying to implement OneDrive connection for my application using [this](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/graph_oauth.htm#code-flow) documentation. I've got the `code` from parameter and was trying to retrieve the `access_token` using Step 2 of the Code flow in documentations. My server is a NodeJS application.

I have a custom service called `restService` for making REST requests from server. Here is the code for it

```
const https = require('https'); 
let makeRequest = (host, endPoint, method, requestOptions={}) => {
    return new Promise ( (resolve, reject) =>{
        var options = {
            host: host,
            port: 443,
            path: endPoint,
            method: method,
            headers :  requestOptions.headers || {}
        };
        var req = https.request(options, function(response) {
            let body = "";
            response.on('data', (d) => {
                body += d;
            });
            response.on('end', function() {
                resolve({
                    statusCode : response.statusCode,
                    body : body
                })
            });
            response.on('error', function() {
               reject("Error while making request");
            });
        });

        if(!!requestOptions.body){
            req.write(requestOptions.body);
        }
        req.on('error', (e) => {
            console.error("ERROR WHILE MAKING API call to " + host + " :", e)
            reject(e);
        });
        req.end();
    })
}
```

Using the above service, I make a request to retrieve access_token as mentioned in the Step 2 of code flow as follows

```
let endpoint = "/common/oauth2/v2.0/token";
let body = "grant_type=authorization_code&client_id="+config.onedrive.client_id
                +"&redirect_uri="+encodeURIComponent(config.onedrive.redirect_uri)
                +"&client_secret="+config.onedrive.client_secret+"&code="+code;
let requestOptions = {
    headers : {
        "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    } ,
    body : body
}
restService.makeRequest("login.microsoftonline.com", endpoint, "POST", requestOptions)
.then( data=>{console.log(data)})
```

But no matter what I do, I get the response

```
{
   statusCode : 404
   body : ""
}
```

from restService.makeRequest(). But, when making the same request from POSTMAN, I'm getting proper response from the endpoint. Please help me debug this.

Answer (score 0):

I added the `'Content-Length'` header in the restService as follows

```
if(!!requestOptions.body){
    requestOptions.headers = requestOptions.headers || {};
    requestOptions.headers['Content-Length'] =  requestOptions.body.length;
}
```

Now its working as expected. Wonder why `login.microsoftonline.com` would return `404` for a missing header.